# React use setState to update object but not re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use setState to update the object in state which called 'all_cart",

but not matter which method I tryed, it cannot trigger re-render, I know React will use `===` to check two object in state is changed or not.

Here is my code:

```
this.setState({
    all_cart: {
        ...this.state.all_cart,
        cart_data : _response['data'].data.cart_data
    }
})

this.setState(({all_cart}) => ({
    all_cart: {
        ...this.state.all_cart,
        cart_data : _response['data'].data.cart_data
    }
}))
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) if you have props, it is wrong approach:

```
// Wrong
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
});
```

> To fix it, use a second form of setState() that accepts a function
> rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state
> as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied
> as the second argument:

```
// Correct
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));
```

And your code would look like this:

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
    all_cart: {
        ...state.all_cart,
        cart_data : _response['data'].data.cart_data
    }
}))
```

**UPDATE:**

However, if you do not use props, then it looks like your function is not is scope, so try to use arrow function. Let me show an example:

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(this.someApiResult())
}
```

So a [complete stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/setstate-dsbcsw?file=index.js) can be seen here.

Comment: I try but still nothing change

Comment: @ChaCha please, see my updated answer

Comment: I'm sorry for that, but is's still not work :(

Comment: @ChaCha please, see a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/setstate-dsbcsw?file=index.js). You can compare your code and try to find differencies. It should work

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to merge *_response['data'].data.cart_data* with the existing state which is *all_cart*,
in this case, you should try this

```
function updateCart(){
const updatedData = {...this.state.all_cart, ..._response['data'].data.cart_data};
this.setState({all_cart: updatedData});
}
```